Renaming AWS GraphQL Schema Types
I have an issue where I created a type called Fixtures but then I realised that it is good practise to always keep it singular with the names as the queries, mutationa and subscriptions that are generated may be plurals.
So How do I change the type name fromFixtures to Fixture
I tried using the instructions to hard reset everything using amplify push --allow-destructive-graphql-schema-updates but it keeps failing with errors saying that some resources exist and those resources are what was generated when i pushed the backend to amplify using amplify push

You can try manual deletion of the existing Fixtures type and any associated resources like tables in DynamoDB, resolvers, and data sources.

So I found a solution,
First I tried to manually delete the table from DynamoDb and also delete the resources that were generated but it didn't work, even told me I had a drift issue. This was driving me crazy.
But what I did next was to restore everything back as it was, ran amplify push --allow-destructive-graphql-schema-updates but this time I removed the Fixtures type from the schema file.
This generated everything without the Fixtures and even deleted the table too from Dynamodb. Afterwards, I just added the Fixture type to the list of types in the schema and ran amplify push to generate the table and resources with the right name. A little bit stressful but it does the job
